# Is there a way to get profile thumbnail photo from Azure AD with Cognito SAML Identity Provider?

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, saml

I'm setting up a new Angular application using AWS Cognito SAML Identity Provider to connect to an existing Azure AD to handle login, logout, sso, token,... and want to display the Azure AD profile photo in my app. Is there a way to achieve my purpose using only regular payload from Cognito + SAML.

I've been researching a way to do that, most 'guides' point to using MS graph API to get the photo from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/ (or somethign similar) but that method would require me to do another login to get  token for the API which would defeat the purpose of using Cognito in my case.

So is there a way to get the photo with the token from Cognito or a way to send back the photo url in the payload or is another auth is required to get the photo from MS Graph?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?